# React routes gives 404 when trying to hit routes with /:id

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, react-router-dom

I inherited a framework for a static website that uses react and react-router-dom for the Routes. We want the website to be able to support dynamic loaded content onto pages via an id.

For example, I have an /articles page that lists all the articles and when you click on one of the listed articles, it opens the url /articles/ABCDEFG and then loads the Article page component and fetches the data for that specific id. This works completely on local dev, however once I deploy to production (hosted as an Azure website application) I get all the pages working except for the ones that have a dynamic URL.

I'm fairly new to react, but from what I've read static react sites can't use the /:id because it requires each page to exist already.

I did a search and tried to remove anything static-related from the server and webconfig.

```
var express = require('express');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var fallback = require('express-history-api-fallback');

var app = express();
var publicDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../www');

// app.use('/', serveStatic(publicDir));
//app.use(fallback('index.html', { root: publicDir }));

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

My routes are set up like this

```
    generateRoutes() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route exact path="/articles" component={Articles} />
                <Route path="/articles/:id" component={Article} />
                <Route exact path="/careers" component={Careers} />
                <Route exact path="/people" component={People} />
                <Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />
            </Switch>
        );
    }
```

What I want is when I put a url into the address bar such as https://example.com/site/profile/246b9e73-5332-4afb-92b8-be5a061bd908 it renders the profile page with that id.

Instead, I get a 404 saying the page can't be found. I'm not sure if I'm chasing a rabbit hole with the static/dynamic idea but I've spent about 2 days trying to figure out why this isn't working so far and I'm willing to try anything.

Comment: I am sure the commented lines in your code snippet was a typing error. If not, uncomment those and try to see if it works.

Comment: your express server needs to render the app (index.html) on all routes (or a catchall `*`) or you wont get the JS / react-router to run

Comment: @JohnRuddell : not necesssary, if express-history-api-fallback is used, which basically does the same thing.

Comment: sure if fallback is not commented out :)

Comment: Also you say your url path is /site/profile/246b...

But your router is only set to /profile/:id

Comment: I commented out those lines to try to see if that would make it not static. As far as I can tell from reading tutorials, the /:id means that will be a parameter instead of an actual page and when the route /profile/:id (or in the example /site/profile/246...) it replaces makes that value on the component as the parameter id. The only difference I saw was instead of fallback hitting the index.html if the page 404'd it would display the 404

Comment: Yes I was simply bringing up the point you have an extra directory '/site/' in the URL but not on your route.

Comment: Oh, yeah. That's cause everything is inside a folder called /site/

Comment: Also, i tried /profile/* instead of profile/:id and it still gave me the 404, but again only on production. Localhost works as expected. Am I supposed to create a folder inside /profile called * with an index.html to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [deployment](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) section in create-react-app has already addressed this issue, stating

> If you use routers that use the HTML5 pushState history API under the hood (for example, React Router with browserHistory), many static file servers will fail. For example, if you used React Router with a route for /todos/42, the development server will respond to localhost:3000/todos/42 properly, but an Express serving a production build as above will not.
>
> This is because when there is a fresh page load for a /todos/42, the
>   server looks for the file build/todos/42 and does not find it. The
>   server needs to be configured to respond to a request to /todos/42 by
>   serving index.html. For example, we can amend our Express example
>   above to serve index.html for any unknown paths:

So, the solution for you is to change

`app.use('/', serveStatic(publicDir));`

to

`app.use('/*', serveStatic(publicDir));`

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried following the documentation linked, which is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve, however that didn't work.

`var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../www')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../www', 'index.html'));
 });

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
`

I also tried changing the routes from /:id to /* but that didn't work either,

Comment: I believe it has something to do with `../www`, is this script running in a sibling directory of `www` ? Also can you confirm `express server` is running is serving the files ?

Comment: So I did some more investigation. It turns out that that server file isn't actually used. The framework just had it there, which is why there was no change when I did the `/*` Do you know if there's a way to replicate that desired in either a web config or webpack.config?

Comment: @John you might have missed the `web.config` setup ??? This might help https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you so much. That's exactly what I needed to get those routes working. With the web.config setup, that handles my routes so I don't need to add a server unless later we decide to go to SSR.